# Adopt a protocol for Array and Dictionary

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, swift-protocols, swift4.1

I have the following protocol:

```
protocol MyProtocol {

    var stringValue: String { get }
}
```

I also implemented it's methods for some classes and structures in extensions:

```
extension Int: MyProtocol {

    var stringValue: String {

        return "IntValue"
    }
}

extension String: MyProtocol {

    var stringValue: String {

        return "StringValue"
    }
}

extension Array: MyProtocol where Element == Dictionary<String, Any> {

    var stringValue: String {

        return "ArrayValue"
    }
}

extension Dictionary: MyProtocol where Key == String, Value == Any {

    var stringValue: String {

        return "DictionaryValue"
    }
}
```

When I tried to test it with the following code:

```
let dict = [["key":"value"]]
let stringValueResult = dict.stringValue
print(stringValueResult)
```

I received an error with text "`[[String : String]]` is not convertible to `Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>`". However my code works fine when I set type of the variable `dict` like that:

```
let dict: Array<Dictionary<String, Any>> = [["key":"value"]]
```

Can someone explain me why the first version of my code is not compiling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this error is the conflict between the `dict` type inferred by the compiler and the one you mentioned while conforming `Array` to your `protocol`.

When you write this line

```
let dict = [["key":"value"]]
```

For compiler it will become as below where type is `Array<Dictionary<String, String>>`

```
let dict: Array<Dictionary<String, String>> = [["key":"value"]]
```

Now when you are doing `dict.stringValue`, compiler will first match the type of the calling object i.e `dict` with the type you defined during conformance of `Array` with `MyProtocol`

As the compiler inferred type i.e, `Array<Dictionary<String, String>>` is different than the type you mentioned in conformance i.e, `Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>` so compiler throws error.

But when you declare `dict` variable with explicit type i.e, `Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>` same as you defined in conformance of `MyProtocol` then compiler does not see any issue and your code works just fine.

While conforming `Array/Dictionary` to `MyProtocol` you can just ignore setting the `Element` type as below,

```
extension Array: MyProtocol {

    var stringValue: String {

        return "ArrayValue"
    }
}

extension Dictionary: MyProtocol {

    var stringValue: String {

        return "DictionaryValue"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change your `Array` and `Dictionary` implementation constraint like this:

```
extension Array: MyProtocol where Element: MyProtocol {

    var stringValue: String {

        return "ArrayValue"
    }
}

extension Dictionary: MyProtocol where Key == String {

    var stringValue: String {

        return "DictionaryValue"
    }
}
```

Now if you run following code it will print: `ArrayValue`

```
let dict = [["key":"value"]]
let stringValueResult = dict.stringValue
print(stringValueResult)
```

Comment: I am getting error `Extension of type 'Array' with constraints cannot have an inheritance clause` and `Extension of type 'Dictionary' with constraints cannot have an inheritance clause` with same code.

Comment: @ChanchalChauhan what version of Swift are you using? The question is about Swift 4.1.

Comment: It's 4.0. Thanks

Comment: @ChanchalChauhan Try to run this code with Swift 4.1 and tell if it works for you.